# Angular Cli not working properly after updating to Angular 6 Version

Tags: angular

[image]

[image]

Fist I updated angular cli to latest version with "npm install -g @angular/cli@next" command after that problem started. ng new projectName not working.

Cli versions I tried 6+ and 1.6 and 1.7, all versions i'm getting same 
problem.

Comment: it appears in bad install, try to remove and installe npm and angular-cli again and it works.

Comment: i did my times still same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below steps one after another.

1. npm i -g @angular/cli@latest
2. npm i --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
3. ng update @angular/cli
4. npm i --save-dev webpack

The above steps install angular 6 and update the whole project to angular 6.

Comment: Same error: Aruns-MacBook-Air:desktop mmnarun$ ng new App 
Tree type is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't just the name is not supported? Name 'test' is also not supported, try generating an app with any other name.

Answer (score 0):

instead of name as app use anyother name like "angular-app", that will work, 
even i am also getting same problem like you,

> Project name "app" is not a supported name.